# Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my entity below I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and H2 as the database.

```
package com.java.webservice.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the TABLE1 database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Table1.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Table1 t")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="INPUT_STRING")
    private String inputString;

    @Column(name="REVERSED_STRING")
    private String reversedString;

    public Table1() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getInputString() {
        return this.inputString;
    }

    public void setInputString(String inputString) {
        this.inputString = inputString;
    }

    public String getReversedString() {
        return this.reversedString;
    }

    public void setReversedString(String reversedString) {
        this.reversedString = reversedString;
    }

}
```

But as I tried to test it using JUnit Test, I got an error like this:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.java.webservice.impl.SpringRestServiceImpl.reversedString(SpringRestServiceImpl.java:21)
    at com.java.webservice.database.SpringRestDatabase.stringReversed(SpringRestDatabase.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_9 ON PUBLIC.TABLE1(ID) VALUES (1, 3)"; SQL statement:
insert into Table1 (INPUT_STRING, REVERSED_STRING, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:103)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:231)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:190)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:704)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:156)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 64 more
```

Below is also my code for DB Unit Testing:

```
package com.java.webservice.database;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;

import com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.DatabaseSetup;
import com.java.webservice.dao.SpringRestDAO;
import com.java.webservice.entity.Table1;
import com.java.webservice.service.SpringRestService;


@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/application-test.xml")
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:spring/data.xml")
public class SpringRestDatabase {

    @Autowired
    private SpringRestService service;

    @Autowired
    private SpringRestDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void findAll(){
        List<Table1> list = (List<Table1>) dao.findAll();
        assertTrue("tupni".equals(list.get(0).getReversedString()));
    }

    @Test
    public void stringReversed(){
        assertTrue("tupni".equals(service.reversedString("input")));
    }

    @Test
    public void inputString(){
        service.inputString("INPUT", "TUPNI");
    }


}
```

Below is SpringRestServiceImpl.java

```
package com.java.webservice.impl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.java.webservice.dao.SpringRestDAO;
import com.java.webservice.entity.Table1;
import com.java.webservice.service.SpringRestService;


@Service
public class SpringRestServiceImpl implements SpringRestService{
    @Autowired
    SpringRestDAO dao; 
    public String reversedString(String string) {
        String result = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
        Table1 entity = new Table1();
        entity.setInputString(string);
        entity.setReversedString(result);
        dao.save(entity);
        return result;
    }
    public Table1 inputString(String inputString, String reversedString) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me how to debug this kind of code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Comment: I tried it but I still got error.

Comment: Please post you `SpringRestServiceImpl` as well. The bug seems to be sitting in your implementation.

Comment: @AbdullahWasi I already added it

Comment: User tries to insert an object with an id that already exists. So answer why you are doing that? and what data is already in the table. Look in the JPA provider log at what is happening

Comment: So obviously, the error is a violation of a PK constraint on your table. That said, can you debug with debug points at (and after) where you instantiated your entity object (so right here Table1 entity = new Table1();)? My guess is that the id value is the same one as in the DB. If that's the case, you may need to try different GenerationTypes. Check out this: (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

Answer (score 3):

Most time, it is because you insert the same primary key twice. Double check the Object you insert into database.

For me, I have config the id auto increment, so I insert id 0 for twice.

Answer (score 2):

You have ti start your script with delete from TABLE_NAME, then you use isert into TABLE_NAME (xx, xx) values (xx,xx).